# Row sum of a dataframe returns zero. (when there are N/As in only a few rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, row

```
df['total'] =df.sum(axis=1)
print(df.tail(5))   
                  Apr 2015 May 2015          Jun 2015          Jul 2015  \
Redmond, WA        21.2594  21.0405  Division by zero  Division by zero   
Plantation, FL     23.8435  25.0725            28.834            23.527   
Lawrenceville, GA  10.7847   10.161           11.7116           14.7928   
Highland Park, IL  21.2594  21.0405           21.1542           21.5423   
Beaverton, OR          n/a      n/a               n/a               n/a   

                           Aug 2015          Sep 2015          Oct 2015  \
Redmond, WA        Division by zero  Division by zero  Division by zero   
Plantation, FL              23.6495             20.69           21.2267   
Lawrenceville, GA           14.1778           12.4531           10.8317   
Highland Park, IL           20.6783           21.0254  Division by zero   
Beaverton, OR                   n/a  Division by zero  Division by zero   

                           Nov 2015          Dec 2015          Jan 2016  \
Redmond, WA        Division by zero  Division by zero  Division by zero   
Plantation, FL                  n/a               n/a               n/a   
Lawrenceville, GA            10.423           10.3803               n/a   
Highland Park, IL  Division by zero  Division by zero  Division by zero   
Beaverton, OR      Division by zero  Division by zero  Division by zero   

                           Feb 2016          Mar 2016  total  
Redmond, WA        Division by zero  Division by zero    0.0  
Plantation, FL                  n/a               n/a    0.0  
Lawrenceville, GA               n/a               n/a    0.0  
Highland Park, IL  Division by zero  Division by zero    0.0  
Beaverton, OR      Division by zero  Division by zero    0.0
```

It returns a column consists of 0.0, which obviously not. Ideally I want the sum of every row, and when there's an N/A or any other text in that row, returns N/A. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: post the output of `print(df.head(10))` in your question, select it and press `Ctrl+K`. And you forgot to ask a question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to remove all the strings in dataframe.
Try this I have only taken a part of your data.

```
df
Out[35]: 
   Apr 2015  May 2015          Jun 2015          Jul 2015          Aug 2015  
    0   21.2594   21.0405  Division by zero  Division by zero  Division by zero   
    1       NaN   23.8435           25.0725               NaN               NaN   
    2   21.2594   21.0405  Division by zero  Division by zero  Division by zero   
    3       NaN   23.8435           25.0725               NaN               NaN   
    4   21.2594   21.0405  Division by zero  Division by zero               n/a   
    5       NaN   23.8435           25.0725               NaN               NaN 



           Sep 2015          Oct 2015          Nov 2015          Dec 2015  
0  Division by zero  Division by zero  Division by zero  Division by zero   
1               NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN   
2  Division by zero  Division by zero  Division by zero  Division by zero   
3               NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN   
4               n/a               n/a  Division by zero  Division by zero   
5               NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN   

           Jan 2016  Feb 2016  Mar 2016  total  
0  Division by zero       NaN       NaN    NaN  
1               NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN  
2  Division by zero       NaN       NaN    NaN  
3               NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN  
4  Division by zero       NaN       NaN    NaN  
5               NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN  

Out[46]:df.replace('Division by zero|n/a','N/A',regex=True,inplace =True)
    df
Out[59]: 
   Apr 2015  May 2015 Jun 2015 Jul 2015 Aug 2015 Sep 2015 Oct 2015 Nov 2015
     0   21.2594   21.0405      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A   
1       NaN   23.8435  25.0725      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
2   21.2594   21.0405      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A   
3       NaN   23.8435  25.0725      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
4   21.2594   21.0405      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A   
5       NaN   23.8435  25.0725      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   

  Dec 2015 Jan 2016  Feb 2016  Mar 2016  total  
0      N/A      N/A       NaN       NaN    NaN  
1      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN  
2      N/A      N/A       NaN       NaN    NaN  
3      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN  
4      N/A      N/A       NaN       NaN    NaN  
5      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN 




Out[50]: df['total']=df.sum(axis=1,skipna=False)

   df
Out[80]: 
   Apr 2015  May 2015 Jun 2015 Jul 2015 Aug 2015 Sep 2015 Oct 2015 Nov 2015 
0   21.2594   21.0405      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A   
1       NaN   23.8435  25.0725      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
2   21.2594   21.0405      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A   
3       NaN   23.8435  25.0725      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   
4   21.2594   21.0405      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A      N/A   
5       NaN   23.8435  25.0725      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   

  Dec 2015 Jan 2016  Feb 2016  Mar 2016  total  
0      N/A      N/A       NaN       NaN    NaN  
1      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN  
2      N/A      N/A       NaN       NaN    NaN  
3      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN  
4      N/A      N/A       NaN       NaN    NaN  
5      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I can't convert all the text to zero, because it doesn't make any sense to add the number if there's missing data, I just want to show that they're missing, so when there's an N/A or any other text in that row, returns N/A. How can I do that?

Comment: check I have updated the answer you can represent the missing values as `N/A` in `replace`.

Comment: That works but in the 'total' column, it still returns a number when there's an N/A in that row.

Comment: ok just one minor change in `df.sum ` add `skipna=False` it works perfectly as you want check it.As I have `N/A` in all rows it shows only `N/A` in `total`.So for you it will work as expected.

Comment: It didn't work again. I'm not sure why it's giving me zero all the time. Should I use df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

Comment: try it I don't know why is it giving zero.